# If set theory only contains the notions of “set” and “is a member of” as primitives, how can an axiom of set theory refer to a “formula”?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, meta-math

It's said that the primitive concepts of set theory are those of "set" and "membership", then all axioms of set theory must begin with "Let $A$ be a set" or "Let $x\in A$", but they don't. For example, let us consider the subset axiom:

**Subset Axiom.** Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula and let $A$ be a set. Then there exists a set $S$ such that for all sets $x$ we have that $x\in S$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $\varphi(x)$.

This axiom begins with "Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula" but "formula" is not a primitive concept, then, for having sense, it must be a defined concept, but as far as I see we can't define "formula" in terms of "set" and "membership" if I am wrong, please tell me. Now, in the case where we can't define "formula", how is the subset axiom justified from a logical point of view?

In many books, when the subset axioms is introduced, the statement "Let $\varphi(x)$" is used informally, I will appreciate if you recommend me a book on set theory where the concept of "formula" is used formally, where there is a formal definition of what a formula is.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: One book that elaborates in quite a bit of detail about the anatomy of formulas (and everything to do with their syntax, such as free variables, bound variables, what an "occurrence" of a variable in a formula means, etc.) is Quine's *Mathematical Logic* (1940). However due to its age it is quite dated and its notation is hard to read (akin to Principia Mathematica), and the axiomatic set theory it presents is somewhat different than ZFC (it presents a system based on [New Foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations)).

Comment: There are many books which define what a “formula” is, but these are usually logic books rather than set theory books. Some examples: Van Dalen, Logic and Structure (terse and concise), Propositional and predicate calculus, Goldrei (good beginner text). In order to study set theory, it helps to have an understanding of logic.

Comment: [Subset Axiom **schema**](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html). See also [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/schema/)

Comment: See also [First-Order Logic and Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490537/first-order-logic-zfc)

Answer (score 21):

In formalizations of set theory (e.g. ZFC), this subset axiom you've described in usually called the **axiom schema of specification**. Note the use of the word "schema" in its name: this is where your confusion stems from. Indeed, formally speaking, this is not a single axiom, but a whole collection of axioms: *one for every formula $\phi(x)$*. For every formula $\phi(x)$, there is an axiom of set theory which goes "$\forall A \exists S \forall x (x \in S \Leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge \phi(x)))$". Taken together, all these axioms make up what you call the subset axiom.

Edit: Axiomatic set theory is based on *first-order logic*, which is the system of language and inferences that are used to do this sort of math. It starts with *symbols* (including variables, connectives like $\neg$ and $\wedge$, quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$, the $=$ symbol, and predicate symbols) which are combined according to certain rules to make *formulas*. First-order logic also uses *rules of inference* to deduce some formulas from others. Set theory uses first-order logic with the predicate symbol $\in$; its axioms and theorems are formulas. I suggest reading some more (on Wikipedia or in your favorite textbook) if you're interested in learning more about how first-order logic works.

Comment: Then what is the formal definition of formula?

Comment: @RataMágica Formulas and first-order logic come "below" set theory, in that axiomatic set theories such as ZFC rest on top of first-order logic. In each language of first-order logic, there is a definition for what a formula is, which is a string of characters $($, $)$, $\land$, $\lnot$, $\lor$, variable symbols, relation symbols, and predicate symbols, which follows the rules for being a wff of that logic. But this is conceptually "below" set theory, and more general, as it also applies for formalizing what a formula is w.r.t. some other axiomatic systems like Peano arithmetic.

Comment: About set theory resting on FOL, this answer sounds relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146487/1030967

Comment: @RataMágica See my edit. Don't forget that you can accept an answer if you believe it resolves your question.

Comment: @RataMágica: To follow up Sambo’s general explanation with examples: A *formula* here means any statement in the logical language we’re using, possibly with free variables — so like “$\exists y,\ y \in x$”, “\forall z, (z \in y \leftrightarrow (z = x_1 \lor z = x_2))”, or in prose, “$x$ is inhabited”, “$y$ is the pair $\{x_1,x_2\}$”.  So (1) each individual instance of the axiom schema doesn’t involve the concept of ‘formula’; and (2) once you’re setting out axioms in a formal language, you’re already talking about formulas (possibly under some other name).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the definition of "formula" doesn't matter to set theory. My understanding is that The first-order logic definition could be written $∀∀∃∀(∈⇔(∈∧()))$, and the definition $(x)$ is no more part of *set theory* than  the definition of $\forall$ or $\exists$.

Comment: @chepner First-order logic doesn't allow you to quantify over formulas $\phi$. For that, you'd need some kind of second-order logic. I'd say that, although the definition of a formula isn't "part of" set theory, it still matters to set theory, precisely because there is a comprehension axiom for each formula.

Comment: @C7X: Your comment here could serve as a very direct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @Sambo I did forget that crucial distinction between first- and second-order logic. But set theory doesn't care what $\phi$ means, right, only that there *is* a separate axiom for each $\phi$?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks! I have now posted it as an answer.

Comment: @chepner What specifically is a definition of formula? If it is a time for which strings are considered wffs, on a lower level (first-order logic) there are some properties the collection of wffs must have for set theory to work properly, for example "if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formulas then $\phi\implies\psi$ is a formula". In this way the choice of formal language is important, and the difficulty of working in a set theory where these kinds of properties are not the case is why well-established languages like first-order logic are what are usually used.

Comment: @Sambo, then are "Let $A$ and $B$ be a set. Then there exists a set $C$ such that for all sets $x$ we have that $x\in C$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $x\in B$" and "Let $A$ and $B$ be a set. Then there exists a set $C$ such that for all sets $x$ we have that $x\in C$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$" both axioms of ZFC and not corollaries of the subset axioms? and to avoid writing one by one of these axioms we use the trick "Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula". Therefore this use of formulas in the subset axiom is like "e.g." when we write.

Comment: @Sambo, and then the use of "Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula" in the subset axioms doesn't have a formal and rigorous justification, rather it is just a trick to simply writing, am I right?

Comment: You are correct that the two statements you've listed are both axioms of ZFC; we might describe them as "instances" of the axiom schema of comprehension. (I should note that, in your examples, $B$ is a free variable. I didn't mention that in my answer, but Wikipedia gives more detail.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that "let $\phi(x)$ be a formula" has no formal and rigorous justification. However, I think what you're getting at is that it isn't part of the formal first-order language used as a basis for ZFC: it isn't part of the (formal) axiom itself. You might say that it's part of the meta-language. I think that this can be circumvented to some extent by using second-order logic instead of first-order, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 3):

Formulas and first-order logic come "below" set theory, in that axiomatic set theories such as ZFC rest on top of first-order logic. In each language of first-order logic, there is a definition for what a formula is, which is a string of characters $($, $)$, $\land$, $\lnot$, $\lor$, variable symbols, relation symbols, and predicate symbols, which follows the rules for being a wff of that logic. But this is conceptually "below" set theory, and more general, as it also applies for formalizing what a formula is w.r.t. some other axiomatic systems like Peano arithmetic, or the group axioms.

About set theory resting on FOL, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146487) answer sounds relevant.