# Landau's "Foundations of Analysis" - Addition of natural numbers

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers

At the beginning of his *Foundations of Analysis* book (translated from German), Landau writes in his *Preface for the Teacher* :

> Peano defines $x+y$ for fixed $x$ and all $y$ as follows :
>   $$x+1 = x' \\ x+y' = (x+y)',$$
>   and he and his successors then think that $x+y$ is defined generally ; for, the set of $y$'s for which it is defined contains $1$, and contains $y'$ if it contains $y$.
>
> But $x+y$ has *not* been defined.
>
> All would be well if - and this is not done in Peano's method because order is introduced only after addition - one had the concept "numbers $\leq y$" and could speak of the set of $y$'s for which there is an $f(z)$, defined for $z \leq y$, with the properties
>   $$f(1) = x, \\ f(z') = (f(z))' \quad \text{for } z < y.$$

Here the prime denotes the successor function. I really don't understand why $x+y$ can't be defined the first way. In fact, Theorem 4 of the book, which is at the same time Definition 1, seems to follow exactly Peano's definition. But, the author actually proves unicity and existence of such a function $+ : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. He fixes an $x$ and shows unicity and existence for all $y$, so that given $(x,y)$, $+(x,y)$ is well defined.

The only difference I see between Peano's and Landau's definitions of natural numbers is that Landau's proves existence by induction on $x$ instead of $y$.

What's the subtlety here ? Why is Peano's definition incorrect ?

Comment: I wondered about this myself about 10 years ago. Thus far I have not seriously studied the issue, but I have managed to collect some relevant literature on the subject, which I posted a few details about a couple of years ago in another group. I brought it up in this [22 November 2011 post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7614303) and provided some literature quotes in this [28 November 2011 post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7617938). Also, at the end of the second post I take a stab at giving a correct proof.

Comment: Thank you for the references. However it seems to me like the proof you give is exactly the same as Landau's existence proof in Theorem 4 of the book. So, if I get it right, Landau's criticism comes from the fact that Peano's definition merely gives the two conditions that $x+$ (preserving JFD's notation) must satisfy, and no proof of existence (that is, of explicit construction of $x+$) and uniqueness is given. Then he says everything would be well if you had ordering at your disposal, because at first he thought that a general iteration theorem (like the one T.A.E. gives below) was needed...

Comment: (Cont.) ... and ordering is needed to prove such a (strong) iteration theorem. But then he says Dr. Kalmár was able to prove that $x+$ is well defined *without* using ordering, and that proof is the proof given of Theorem 4 (which, for the existence part, coincides with the proof you posted in another group). Finally he says that such simple proofs relying solely on induction can't be found when we define general finite sums and products, but that is not a problem since ordering is available at that point. Is this correct ? In the end the "*not* defined" written by Landau...

Comment: (Cont.) ... refers to the lack of *construction* of $x+$ in Peano's definition ?

Comment: I've been really busy all day today at work and just now saw that you made some comments. Tomorrow I'll look over what you said (when I should be fresher) and let you know what I think, if anything (I'm not much of an expert on these foundational type matters).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to be of much help after all. I've looked over my proof from two years ago, and I think it addresses the shortcomings that Landau said was in an earlier edition of his book, but I'm not really sure how the ordering issues you cite are involved. One thing, perhaps very basic but I'll say it anyway, is that we are allowed to assume the existence of the successor function, which gets things off the ground so to speak. Confusingly subtle issues like this, which I have bumped into several times over the years, is a large part of my motivation for studies **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** such as I describe in [this StackExchange post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140681/where-to-begin-with-foundations-of-mathematics/141160#141160).

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for taking time to answer back ! As for the assumed existence of the successor function, it does not bother me at all. Reading Landau's book, I take for granted such set-theoretic issues. I plan to read Suppes' *Axiomatic Set Theory*, and I know that he derives Peano's axioms for natural numbers from the ZF axioms. So he must show that such a successor function exists (in ZF). One thing at a time :). Greetings !

Comment: @Guest: Can you tell me where in this question (or in the comments and answers) my question, "After some thinking I found out that the definition of addition (as has been presented in the quoted portion) assumes that starting from any $y$, we can eventually reach $1$. But this is not obvious (at least to me) from the Principle of Mathematical Induction (if it is please give hints to the proof). Maybe that was a flaw in the definition?" is answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something such as the iteration theorem should be proved first:
(P,S,1) is a Peano system
W is a set, $c \in W$, $g : W\rightarrow W.$
Conclusion: There exists a unique function $F: P \rightarrow W$ such that
(a) F(1)=c
(b) F(S(x))=g(F(x)).

One can then apply the iteration theorem to $W=P$ and $g=S$ in order to obtain the existence of a unique binary operation + on $P$ such that
(a) x + 1 = S(x)
(b) x+S(y)=S(x+y) for all $x,y \in P$.

Answer (score 4):

In 1889, Peano published the list of axioms that is now named after him. He thought that his recursive definitions of addition and multiplication were intuitively and obviously consistent, offering no justification at all for it:

> He evidently thought that these equations in themselves define the addition and multiplication functions uniquely. He failed to realize the necessity for a proof that there are indeed functions satisfying them. There is therefore a lacuna in Peano's account at just this point.$^{[1]}$

When Landau says that “$x+y$ has *not* been defined”, he's criticizing Peano for not justifying *formally* that his recursive definition of $+$ is correct as far as *existence* and *unicity* are concerned. More generally, Landau is saying that such recursive definitions should have a rigorous foundation, which is the Recursion Theorem that was published by Dedekind in 1888. This is the theorem that Peano dismissed in his 1889 publication. In fact, Landau himself dismissed it in the first draft of his book:

> It is a mark of the significance of Dedekind's achievement that Peano was not the only mathematician of stature to miss the need for it: Landau, for example, omitted the proof from the first draft of his account of arithmetic in 1930 and was saved from error in the published version only by the intervention of a colleague.$^{[1]}$

The statement of the Recursion Theorem is the following.

> **Recursion Theorem** (Dedekind, 1888). Let $A$ be an arbitrary set containing an element $a\in A$, and a given mapping $g:A\to A$ of $A$ into itself. Then there is one and only one mapping $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to A$ with the two following properties:
>   $$
> \phi(0)=a\tag{1},
> $$
>   $$
> \phi(n+1)=g(\phi(n))\tag{2}.
> $$

A proof (essentially by induction) of this theorem can be found at pp. 16-17 of [2].

> What misled Landau was no doubt the following short but fallacious argument for Dedekind's result. Equation $(1)$ enables us to define $\phi(0)$ uniquely. And if $\phi(n)$ is defined uniquely, equation $(2)$ enables us to define $\phi(n + 1)$ uniquely. Hence by induction the two equations together define $\phi(n)$ uniquely for every natural number $n$. The fallacy in this argument lies in the potential ambiguity of saying that $\phi(n)$ is ‘defined uniquely’ in advance of a proof that the function $\phi$ exists.$^{[1]}$

Since the Recursion Theorem is general, it can be used to justify the definitions of sum and product of natural numbers. However, it doesn't appear in Landau's book. Instead, more direct (and simple) proofs of existence and unicity for $+$ and $\times$ are given. These have been found by Dr Kalmár, as Landau confesses in his preface.

**Sources**:

[1] Potter, M. (2000), *Reason’s Nearest Kin*. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

The three excerpts are from pp. 82-83.

[2] H.-D. Ebbinghaus, H. Hermes, K. Lamotke, H. L. S. Orde et J. H. Ewing (1991)
 *Numbers*. Graduate texts in mathematics, Springer.

The original version is called *Zahlen*.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that Peano only defines (by induction over $y$) a function $x+ : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ for an arbitrary (but fixed) $x\in \mathbb{N}$, and misses an argument for how to combine these infinitely many definitions into one function $+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Landau instead defines (by induction over $x$) the functions $x+ : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, (he uses induction over $y$ to prove uniqueness of each such function), and because he defined all these functions by induction over $x$, he is able to combine them into one function $+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$: the set of $x$'s for which this function is "defined for all $y$" contains $1$, and with $x$ contains $x'$.

Comment: Ok, but if you consider an arbitrary $x$ and show unicity and existence of $x+$ having the two properties, then haven't you proved that the set of $x$'s for which this function is "defined for all $y$" is $\mathbb{N}$ ? In other words, if you want to show that something is true for all $x$'s, isn't it sufficient to prove it for an *arbitrary* $x$, which is what Peano's definition suggests ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the real problem is that Peano has not stated a "recursion theorem", i.e., it is unclear how $x+y' = (x+y)'$ defines anything at all, as on the face of it, it is just a recursive equation for $+$.  So it would be ok if Peano would show uniqueness and existence of all the $x+$ functions, but he doesn't.