# New to logic, what should I study first?

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question, first-order-logic

What are the different types of logic, like formal logic, propositional logic, predicate logic, first order logic, etc and how are they the same and how are they different. And if I was going to start studying one of them, what should I start with?

Comment: Wikipedia anyone of those words will get you basic intro with references. Where to start depends on your goals: math? try Tarski Intro to Logic; computer science? try Hindley-Seldin Intro Lambda Calculus & Combinators; philosophy? try Carveth Reed Logic Inductive & Deductive. But these are just opinions involving somewhat inexpensive books.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662417/recommendation-on-a-rigorous-and-deep-introductory-logic-textbook) for refernces.

Comment: (1) If you haven't already, learn a programming language. Write a few simple programs with lots of different if-statements. (2) Learn how to manually make truth tables for arbitrary statements, tautologies, contradictions and logical equivalences. (3) Google "Software to learn the basic methods of mathematical proof".

Comment: I really don't see how learning a programming language and writing lots of if-statements has much to do with the poster's question. I say this as someone with a PhD in mathematical logic, and decades of experience as a programmer.

Comment: Possibly relevant is the MSE question [Where to begin with foundations of mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140681/13130). See also Peter Smith's very extensive [Teach Yourself Logic. A Study Guide (and other Book Notes)](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/).

Comment: @MichaelWeiss It depends on what the OP meant by "new to logic." I took it to mean, not even experience with logical operators like those in programming languages, e.g. IF A=0 OR B=1 THEN DO X. If the OP had just successfully completed a proof-based course in real analysis or group theory, that would be an entirely different story. Then he or she might be ready for a course mathematical logic.

Comment: @DanChristensen Even so, this strikes me as going all the way round Robin Hood's barn to learn propositional logic. (1) If-then statements are a small part of any programming language. (2) OTOH, $\rightarrow$ is just one of the connectives. (3) You don't have to write lots of if-statements to understand the concept. (4) The poster indicated his interest in predicate logic as well. (5) If a poster asked how they should start learning to program, you wouldn't suggest they begin with a book on mathematical logic, would you? I don't think the converse is different.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I wouldn't recommend a book on mathematical logic unless you had already internalized how classical symbolic logic actually works and what it can be used for. Computer programming is a good place to start on that quest.

Comment: @DanChristensen Right -- a book on mathematical logic would help with only a very small part of learning how to program; also, most of the book would be irrelevant to that task. And vice versa.

Comment: @Algeboy thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of introductory books on mathematical logic; I will mention just a couple, and then attempt to answer your question.

- *Introoduction to Mathematical Logic*, by Elliott Mendelson
- *A Course on Mathematical Logic*, by S.M. Srivastava

"Formal logic" and "mathematical logic" mean pretty much the same. A very large and important part of this is the study of so-called first-order theories. As an example of a statement of a first-order theory, consider this, from the first-order theory of fields:

$$\forall x[\neg (x=0)\rightarrow\exists y(x\cdot y=1)]$$

which means:

> for all $x$, if $x\neq 0$ then there exists a $y$ such that $x\cdot y=1$

The symbols $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$ are called propositional connectives; they stand for "not" and "implies". Other such connectives are $\wedge$ and $\vee$, standing for "and" and "or". You can study the use and meaning of these connectives apart from the other aspects of first-order logic. For example, the part inside the brackets of the above statement has the form $\neg A\rightarrow B$.

*Propositional logic* is this study; it's the most basic layer of formal logic (also the oldest historically). Here's an example: $\neg(A\wedge B)$ is true precisely when $(\neg A)\vee(\neg B)$ is true, regardless of what assertions $A$ and $B$ stand for.

Things start to get more interesting when we add the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ ("for all" and "there exists") into the mix, along with symbols for relations (like $\lt$, =), properties (also called predicates), constants (like 0 and 1), and functions and operators (+, $\cdot$). A *first-order language* is what results. The particular collection of relations, functions, etc. will depend on the subject area. Add in axioms written in this language, and you have a first-order theory. The first-order theory of fields, for example, uses the constants 0 and 1 and the operator symbols + and $\cdot$.

Some stuff is true across *all* first-order theories. Example: $\neg\forall x(A(x))$ is true precisely when $\exists x(\neg A(x))$ is. Here $A(x)$ is some property of $x$ (e.g., $x=0$). The study of this universally true stuff is called *predicate logic*.

(In practice, "first-order logic" and "predicate logic" mean nearly the same thing. It's not worth spending too much time trying to draw distinctions between these terms.)

There's another dimension to all this. The study of formal logic can be divided into syntax, semantics, and proof theory. *Syntax* refers to the precise rules for forming statements in the formal language. For example, $\neg A\vee B$ is a well-formed expression in the propositional calculus, $A\neg B\vee$ is not. This is the most basic aspect of formal logic (and the most boring, IMO, but like practicing scales in music, it's essential).

*Semantics* refers to the meaning of the expressions of the formal language. For propositional logic, truth-tables can be used to specify the semantics. For predicate logic, it's a more complicated story.

Finally, the term *proof theory* is, I hope, suggestive on its own without further explanation. But a great deal of the non-obvious lies behind those innocent two words.

Almost any introductory textbook will begin with syntax and proposition logic, then move onto predicate logic and first-order theories. After that it may consider particular first-order theories of special importance in the history of logic: number theory and set theory. Gödel's famous incompleteness theorem, for example, is a result about first-order number theory. (As it turns out, this theorem also applies more widely.) Mendelson's text follows this route.

One more thing: the examples I gave may seem rather boring. I haven't said anything about what makes mathematical logic interesting. Had I written about that, I wouldn't have addressed your question. It's as if you posted a question about the French language, and I discussed conjugations and parts of speech, but never mentioned Flaubert or Proust.