# Advancing in math

Tags: education

**If this question have already been answered or doesn't belong in this forum I am sorry.**

I am currently in my second year in high school and i am planning on studying economics and finance in college (University of St.Gallen, Switzerland most likely). I have always been able to grasp concepts and since starting high school I have been amongst the best in my class.

The problem is that in middle-school I skipped a lot of classes and I had no ambitions in school. It did especially affect my math grades which were horrible. Today i am very serious about school, but I am still struggling in math. I think that my lack of foundation (almost three years where i did not pick a math book) in math is hindering me in really grasping and understanding the concepts in math.

So my question is how could I build a strong foundation in math which will help me get through in business school. Do you have any great tips for books, websistes, programs etc.

Comment: How about getting a tutor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to begin with foundations of mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140681/where-to-begin-with-foundations-of-mathematics)