# Is there an advantage to using polish notation in terms of human readability?

Tags: logic, soft-question

Lately I've been reading a lot of questions and answers related to logic and I have found some of them in the style of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426109). As I'm not a fan of using Polish notation,  I honestly just skip them. But, now that I think about it I guess there should be a reason for doing it that way.

What I'm asking you guys about is not just what you think, but also of course according to your experience, and if you have something to support your opinion or references. If you ask me I would say the notation is awful, messy, difficult for humans to interpret, and of course non-standard, but it's just my personal opinion and I have nothing to support it other than my very short experience in the area.

Comment: No, there is no advantage for human readability.  This is the reason that Polish notation is not used in mathematical logic publications such as papers and textbooks.  It has hypothetical advantages only in that it can make writing a parser slightly easier in computer languages, but ordinary mathematical writing - even of formal logic - is intended for humans rather than computers.

Comment: I think Łukasiewicz felt that there were advantages for human readers in a notation that avoided brackets (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). He and his followers continued to use the notation, particularly in connection with his many-valued logic. But it has not stood the test of time in logic generally. Even in the literature on Łukasiewicz logic, post-60s papers generally use infix notation. The MSE posts you see using Polish notation are (I think) all from one latter-day enthusiast, who (I hope) will comment on this.

Comment: I think most readers here skip Doug Spoonwood's postings for exactly that reason.

Comment: There is one argument to be made about Polish notation: It's quite useful, when one wants to build a structure on formulae by recursion on their complexity. In fact, the only time I ever explicitly developed a Gödelization (that included metadata about the underlying formula - such as its free variables and number complexity in terms of the Lévy hierarchy), I found it much easier to handle. Arguably, this is not about human readability per se, but somewhat relevant, I think.

Answer (score 2):

From 1990 to 2003, HP produced a series of calculators, the [HP 48 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_48_series), using Reverse Polish Notation (RPN).
Since this series has been quite popular, many (human) users had to adapt themselves to RPN. It was not exactly easy, but with some training, you could get used to it. Writing formulas in RPN usually asked for less symbols than with a traditional notation.

The programming language [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) makes use of the Polish prefix notation. Again, programming in Lisp requires some practice (and not being allergic to parentheses). The choice of the Polish notation was motivated by the fact that it is easy to parse into syntax trees.

I wonder whether Human readibility do not mainly depend on education and training. After all, English is written from left to right, but Arabic and Hebrew go from right to left and [boustrophedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) can be found in ancient manuscripts.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning boustrophedon and lisp. (The programming language [forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) also deserves a mention.) With reverse Polish calculators, it's a matter of a process that users get used to: 2=3=4=+* makes the calculator display 14, but is a hideous as a notation for the expression  2*(3+4). Infix notation for binary operators has become ingrained, and I'd be interested to know more about the history of that.

Comment: The calculator was meant for calculating. Polish notation was invented for proofs. Notice how we denote "do this first" without any parentheses.   * + 3 4 2

Answer (score 0):

It's more algorithm- and machine-friendly than human-friendly. Polish notation, especially reverse Polish notation (the less human-friendly of the two forms) is easy to parse.