# A question about an axiomatization for positive implicational calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Positive Implicational Logic can be axiomatized as follows:

P1: $\phi \to \psi \to \phi$

P2: $(\phi \to \psi) \to (\psi \to \chi) \to \phi \to \chi$

P3: $(\phi \to (\phi \to \psi)) \to \phi \to \psi$

Inspired by this post [Proving $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90340/proving-p-to-q-to-r-to-p-to-q-to-p-to-r), I decided to try to figure out an axiomatization of similar “complexity” using

$(\phi \to \psi) \to (\chi \to \phi) \to \chi \to \psi$

instead of P2.

I came up with the following:

P1: $\phi \to \psi \to \phi$

P2’: $(\phi \to \psi) \to (\chi \to \phi) \to \chi \to \psi$

P3’: $(\phi \to (\psi \to (\phi \to \chi))) \to \psi \to \phi \to \chi$

Is P3’ the simplest axiom that can be added to P1 and P2’ to yield Positive Implicational Calculus, aside from the Frege/distribution axiom? Also, I’m aware that axioms usually (always?) correspond to some sort of combinator. Is there a known combinator that corresponds to P3’?

Comment: The combinator that corresponds to P3' is a combinator $H$ obeying the reduction rule $Hfxy \rightarrow fyxy$.